# Is $H^0(S^0;G)\simeq G\oplus G$ or $G$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In the article on topospaces for the [(co)homology of spheres](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Sphere#Cohomology_groups_and_cohomology_ring), it says $H^0(S^n,G)\simeq H^n(S^n,G)\simeq G$. Is this true when $n=0$?

I think not, for if we view $S^0$ as the union of two $0$-simplices $u$ and $v$, we get the simplicial chain
$$
\cdots\to 0\to 0\to\langle u,v\rangle\to 0
$$
which dualizes to
$$
\cdots\leftarrow 0\leftarrow 0\leftarrow\mathrm{hom}(\langle u,v\rangle, G)\leftarrow 0
$$
where all maps everywhere are $0$. Then wouldn't $H^0(S^0)=\mathrm{hom}(\langle u,v\rangle,G)\simeq G\oplus G$?

Comment: I think it is $G$ if you consider the reduced version of cohomology, otherwise it should be $G\oplus G$.

Comment: if you consider the reduced version, then the statement becones false for $S^n$ with $n>0$ :-)

Comment: Sure, I was just referring to $S^{0}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$H^0(X;G)$ is a direct product of as many copies of $G$ as path-connected components $X$ has.

Your computation is correct.